# Pricing perpetual American put option when interest rate is equal to 0

Tags: option-pricing, american-options, put

Let us consider perpetual American put option with interest rate: $r = 0$.

The Black-Scholes equation in this case has the form:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 S^2 \frac{d^2 V(t, S)}{dS^2} + (r-d)S \frac{dV(t, S)}{dS} - rV(t, S) = 0.
$$

After applying PDE method I obtained that:
$$
V(S) = A S^{\frac{2d+\sigma^2}{\sigma^2}}+ B,
$$
when $2d+\sigma^2\geq0$.

Then using the fact that $V(S)\rightarrow 0$ when $S\rightarrow +\infty$ I have to set $A = 0$ and $B = 0$.

Finally, I obtained:
$$
V(S) = 0.
$$

I interpret it in the way that this option is worthless.

Hence, the stopping region is an empty set, and continuation region has the form: 
$C = \mathbb{R}^{+}$, because there is no optimal moment to exercise this option.

My question is:

1. Is this solution correct?
2. If I obtain that an option is worthless, which means that: $V(S) = 0$ can I say that continuation region is $\mathbb{R}^{+}$?

Comment: An European put does not have value $0$ when the interest rate is null, I don't see why a perpetual American put would have a lower value.

Comment: You are right, so it is a mistake in my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDE doesn't equal zero when I replace with the expression of $V(S)$ you gave. Threre is an issue in your PDE's the boundary conditions and its solution.

Let's start with the regular american put PDE, and deduce the perpetual american put ones, then solve for the price:

**Regular american put**

- Black scholes PDE is satisfied by the price for $S(t) > S^*(t), t < T$
- On $S(t) = S^*(t)$, $V(S(t), t, T) = K - S^*(t)$
- With a final condition: $V(S, T, T) = (K - S(T))^+$
- And the additional condition $\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}(S^*(t), t) = -1$ (we need this an additional equation to be able to solve for $V$ and $S^*$ at the same time).

**Perpetual american put**

Now, for the perpetual american, the value shouldn't depend on time, only on the level of the underlying: $$V_\infty(S, t) = V_\infty(S) = \lim_{(T - t) \rightarrow \infty} V(S,t,T)$$

Doing a change of variable $\theta = T - t$, and denoting $S^*_\infty = \lim_{\theta \rightarrow \infty} S^*(\theta)$ in the equations above gives:

- Black Scholes PDE for $S > S^*_\infty$
- $V_\infty(S^*_\infty) = K - S^*_\infty$
- $\frac{\partial V_\infty}{\partial S}(S^*_\infty) = -1$

Seeking a solution of the form $A S^\alpha + B S^\beta$, we have:

- $\alpha, \beta = \frac{-(r-d-0.5\sigma^2) +/-\sqrt{(r-d-0.5\sigma^2)^2 + 2r\sigma^2}}{\sigma^2} $.

  - if $r = 0$ and $d + 0.5 \sigma^2 \geq 0$, then $\alpha >0$ and $\beta = 0$, in this case we have no solution (the put price should be between $K$ and $K-S$)
  - if $r = 0$, and $d + 0.5 \sigma^2 < 0$, then  $\alpha = 0$ and $\beta < 0$. In this case, $A = 0$ because $V(S)$ should be zero when $S \rightarrow \infty$ (argument that you made)

The last two equations above give in this case $B{S^*_\infty}^\beta = K - S^*_\infty$ and $\beta B {S^*_\infty}^{-1} = -1$

Which leads to:
$$ V_\infty(S) = (K - S^*_\infty) \left( \frac{S}{S^*_\infty} \right)^\beta $$
where: $S^*_\infty = \frac{\beta}{\beta - 1} K$

Comment: I am sorry, I wanted to write: "Then using the fact that $V(S)\rightarrow 0$ when $S\rightarrow \infty$ I have to set $A=0$ and $B=0$. I edited now my main post.

Comment: Ah ok, it's clearer now indeed. However, I think there's something off with the solution of the PDE when r = 0. I substituted your function but didn't get zero :/ Conceptually, if r = 0 and d > 0 your stock price will be eventually reach zero, so I'd expect the price of the perpetual put to be equal to K rather than 0.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but if I assume that $V(S) = K$ for all S, then the condition which states that $V(S)\rightarrow 0$ when $S\rightarrow\infty$ will not hold. The second thing which seems to be strange for me is the fact that the maximum possible payoff for this option is equal to $K$, so selling this option for K creates a situation in which the seller cannot lose money. In the worst situation he/she will have $0$ at the end.

Comment: I had a look, and have rewritten a clearer solution. You were close but some bits were missing.

Comment: I cannot fully agree with your solution. If I assume that $d+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}<0$, then your solution is correct and I understand it. But, as I wrote in my first post, I am curious about the case: $d+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\geq 0$. Then, according to your solution: $\beta = 0$, hence $S_{\infty}^{*} = 0$ and finally $V_{\infty}(S) = K$ for $S>0$, so the condition: $V(S)\rightarrow 0$ when $S\rightarrow \infty$ does not hold.

Comment: Agreed. I have overlooked the case where $d + \frac{1}{2} \sigma ^2 \geq 0$. In this case, the drift is negative: $- d -\frac{1}{2} \sigma ^2 \leq 0$ and there is no solution. The holder will never exercise as they'll keep waiting for the stock to hit zero. The price will get arbitrarily close to zero but will never hit zero (it is lognormal).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Intuitively, I agree with you. But this situation seems to be a little bit strange for me that there is no solution, It is the first time that I encounter such situation. Once again, thank you!

Comment: I thought about it a bit, and updated my solution accordingly to make it clearer for everybody. Now, you can see why (mathematically) there is no solution when $r = 0$ and $d + 0.5\sigma^2 \geq 0$. Please let me know if anything is still not clear.

Comment: I think that you made a small mistake, when $r = 0$ and $d+0.5\sigma^2\geq 0$, then $\beta = 0$. You wrote that $\alpha = 0$. Otherwise everything is clear for me :)

Comment: I clarified a bit the answer and corrected the typo. Please validate the answer if you are satisifed so that other ppl asking the same question can find it easily. Thanks!